# How to match messages coming from several nodes to be able to cross-reference data based on timestamps?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, message-filters, timesynchronizer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I was wondering whether it is possible to cache two synced messages with message_filters API in Melodic?

I got two synced messages:

```
using namespace sensor_msgs; 
message_filters::Subscriber<Image> depth_sub(nodeHandle, "/camera/depth/image_raw", 1);      
message_filters::Subscriber<LaserScan> laser_sub(nodeHandle, "/scan", 1);                    
message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<Image, LaserScan> sync(depth_sub, laser_sub, 10);
```

And I tried to cache it:

```
message_filters::Cache< <Image, LaserScan>> cache(sync, 20);
```

But it didn't work:

```
 /home/alfierra/catkin_ws/src/distance_estimator/src/DistanceEstimator.cpp:11:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid message_filters::Cache< <Image, LaserScan>> cache(sync, 20);
```

Is there any way to achieve that?
Example code to reproduce:

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/cache.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>

using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image, const CameraInfoConstPtr& cam_info)
{
  // Solve all of perception here...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "vision_node");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> image_sub(nh, "image", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<CameraInfo> info_sub(nh, "camera_info", 1);
  TimeSynchronizer<Image, CameraInfo> sync(image_sub, info_sub, 10);

  // my attempt 
  Cache< <Image, LaserScan>> cache(sync, 20);  

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

> To avoid an xy-problem, could you
> please explain to readers here why you
> want to do this?

I'm implementing a package for a robot equipped with a LIDAR and RGBD camera. The robot is supposed to detect objects (chair, person, etc) and estimate the distance to them. The task of the first node is to analyze camera feed, detect objects and publish relevant information (class label and coords of rectangle that encloses the object). The second node's task is to estimate distance to each of detected objects. It subscribes to the first node but it also needs sensor information (Lidar scan and RBGD image) in order to estimate distance. That's why I need a Cache: to be able to store sensor data and retrieve a sample that corresponds to the timestamp of analyzed image.

I thought that synchronizing laserScan and RGBDImage msgs and caching them would be an elegant solution. Although if it's not supported, I'll just cache them independently.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339961/how-to-match-messages-coming-from-several-nodes-to-be-able-to-cross-reference-data-based-on-timestamps?/) by [endrju](https://answers.ros.org/users/50306/endrju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-12-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-15**:
To avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info), could you please explain to readers here why you want to do this?

**Comment by [endrju](https://answers.ros.org/users/50306/endrju/) on 2019-12-15**:
Thanks, I edited the post.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-15**:
It would seem this is an xy-problem: you'd like to be able to match messages coming from several nodes to be able to cross-reference data based on timestamps.

Your question title does not reflect this.

You may want to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The second node's task is to estimate distance to each of detected objects. It subscribes to the first node but it also needs sensor information (Lidar scan and RBGD image) in order to estimate distance. That's why I need a Cache: to be able to store sensor data and retrieve a sample that corresponds to the timestamp of analyzed image.

So if I understand you correctly, you have:

- node 1: takes in camera image, outputs (a list of) detected/identified objects
- node 2: takes in laserscan, rgbd and (lists of) detected/identified objects, outputs: estimated distances

if this is correct, wouldn't it make sense to:

- have node 1 publish its messages with the timestamp of the incoming image (in which the objects were detected)
- have node 2 synch all three topics (ie: laserscan, rgbd and (lists of) detected/identified objects) and always process the three-tuple?

No `Cache` needed, and you still have access to the LaserScan and RGBD data which corresponds to the RGB image's stamps in which the objects were detected.

---

The main point here is: if processing sensor data, think carefully about which timestamp you should associate with the results of that processing. For things like object recognition based on images (or laserscans, lidar, pointclouds, whatever) it's often desirable to associate the timestamp of the original sensor data with the output, as it allows matching the objects with other sensor data captured at the same time.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [endrju](https://answers.ros.org/users/50306/endrju/) on 2019-12-15**:
You understood correctly. Your solution is much simpler - although won't the delay be a problem here? Camera outputs ~90 fps, lidar publishes ~40 scans per second. The first node with my current setup is capable of analyzing ~15 fps (it doesn't buffer any frames, always takes the most recent one). Is TimeSynchronizer able to synchronize msgs that are so desynchronized? (15fps -> ~66ms of delay). Okey while I was writing this I thought I may as well check the docs -> the queue size is parameterized. This one I missed previously ;) Thanks for help!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-15**:\

> Okey while I was writing this I thought I may as well check the docs -> the queue size is parameterized.

you'll indeed need to make sure your `message_filter` has a sufficiently long queue.

But with a plain `Cache` you'd have the same requirement.